# ConcurrentModificationException while making .removeAll() method

Tags: java, list, arraylist, concurrentmodificationexception

I have code looks like this

```
public class ListAnalyzer {
public static List<String> base;

public static void addOfflineToBase(String offline) {
    base.add(offline);
}

public static List<String> prepareArrayList() throws IOException {
    base = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/Users/noname/Desktop/test.txt").toAbsolutePath().normalize());
    List<String> part = base.subList(0, 200);
    base.removeAll(part);
    saveBase();
    return part;
}
```

And when i try to run it - i see:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.util.ConcurrentModificationException' exception.
```

On the line when i try to base.removeAll(part)
I can`t see conflict here. Can someone help me, please?
BTW: saveBase() just writes data to textfile
UPD: Stacktrace

````
21:59:26: Executing task 'App.main() --scan'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :App.main() FAILED
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no] Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1445)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1185)
 at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.isEmpty(AbstractCollection.java:87)
 at com.lukaspradel.steamapi.webapi.request.GetPlayerSummariesRequest$GetPlayerSummariesRequestBuilder.<init>(GetPlayerSummariesRequest.java:41)
 at hexlet.code.App.getOnlineIds(App.java:39)
 at hexlet.code.App.start(App.java:21)
 at hexlet.code.App.main(App.java:16)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':App.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 337ms

```lang-none
````

Comment: You marked the list as static. All instances of your class share the same list base

Comment: I don`t have any instances of this class. I just use it like storage

Comment: Post the complete stack trace please.

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal check the UPD please

Comment: The exception is actually coming from your GetPlayerSummariesRequest.java file. Please post the contents of that file.

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal its coming from GetPlayerSummariesRequest because it works with list, which im trying to sublist. prepareArrayList() returns empty sublist, thats why i got error from this method. I need to understand how i can safely remove strings from base

Comment: The  cause for `ConcurrentModificationException` is probably an attempt to iterate over a collection (in this case a List) while changing the same collection. For more help post [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to understand how i can safely remove strings from `base`.

There are two ways:

1. Add some application level locking so that you don't try to remove strings from the list while something else is iterating the list.
2. Use a concurrent collection type instead of a `List`.  (It is not clear what collection type would be most appropriate.  There isn't a suitable concurrent list type; i.e. one that supports efficient update.)  The concurrent collection types are defined in the `java.util.concurrent` [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem comes from these lines:

```
List<String> part = base.subList(0, 200);
base.removeAll(part);
```

The list `part` is actually backed by the list `base`, so changes in `base` are reflected in `part`. That might cause such exception.

To confirm that, could you please try:

```
List<String> part = new ArrayList<>(base.subList(0, 200));
base.removeAll(part);
```

Another possibility, which does something different, but similar to yours:

```
 base.subList(0, 200).clear();
```

That will remove all elements in the range of 0 to 200, provided all elements are unique.